# SSH "refused key" only with public IP, works locally

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-mint

So my issue is that I'm unable to connect to my SSH server (running on Linux Mint Sarah) from my client (Windows 7 via PuTTY). Only works through the local IP.

Both server and client are on the same subnet. The SSH server is set up to allow only SSH-RSA key connections without passwords. I've installed a key and this is successfully working as desired when I connect to the server's local IP.

I've opened port 22 in my WAN device's firewall, and I can confirm it connects to the right box when I attempt the public IP, because ticking the server's firewall on/off causes rejections. So the SSH connection is successfully reaching the server, attempting to authenticate with the private key, but fails with:

```
Server refused our key
```

Sounds obvious, but I don't see why the key fails to authenticate when I can succeed with the same key locally. This issue has been difficult to research because most results are incorrect port-forwarding.

This is what I've tried (following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-ssh-keys-with-putty-to-connect-to-a-vps) guide, among others):

- Updated all packages on the server and `apt-get install openssh-server`.
- In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I've set:

  - `Port 22`
  - `AllowUsers user`
  - `PasswordAuthentication no`
  - `UsePAM no`
- In PuTTYgen, created a public and private key saved to a directory (in Windows).
- In `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`, copied the part of the public key starting with `ssh-rsa` and ending with `== comment` on a single line with a carriage return at the end.
- `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` which lists under `ls -al` as `drwx------`
- `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` which lists under `ls -l` as `-rw-r--r--`
- In PuTTY, under SSH > Auth, set "Private key for authentication" to the private key generated earlier.
- Connect to port 22 as `user@<local_ip>`... succees.
- Connect to port 22 as `user@<public_ip>`... `Server refused our key`.

As a bonus, `tail`ing `/var/log/auth.log` gives me nothing when the key is refused. When connecting locally, it prints an `Accepted publickey` line.

Lastly, and I'm not sure if this is relevant, but trying to connect with SFTP with FileZilla on the public IP gives me this error:

```
Error:  The first key-exchange algorithm supported by the server is diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, which is no longer secure. Aborting connection.
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

To say I'm an intermediate Linux user would be a stretch, so perhaps I'm overlooking something. I hope I made my problem clear. Appreciate any help!

---

Edit: Output from PuTTY's SSH packets and raw data (mostly garbage, so included what I found to be human readable):

```
Event Log: Looking up host "<omitted>"
Event Log: Connecting to <omitted> port 22
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.67
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-dropbear_0.46
Event Log: We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
Event Log: Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group1"
Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Event Log: Host key fingerprint is:
Event Log: ssh-rsa 1040 <omitted>
Outgoing packet #0x2, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
Event Log: Initialised triple-DES CBC client->server encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Incoming packet #0x2, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
Event Log: Initialised triple-DES CBC server->client encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Incoming packet #0x4, type 51 / 0x33 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 12 70 75 62 6c 69 63 6b 65 79 2c 70 61  ....publickey,pa
  00000010  73 73 77 6f 72 64 00                             ssword.
Event Log: Server refused our key
```

Comment: Do you know how to do that with PuTTY? I have no `ssh` command in cmd. I suppose I could try installing the private key on the server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line makes me suspect you're actually connecting to your router or modem when you connect to port 22 on your public IP.

`Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-dropbear_0.46`

If you connect using the internal IP, do you get the same Server version line? 
If not, you probably need to disable SSH on your modem and/or router and setup port forwarding (if not already done) for port 22 to your Linux server internal IP.

If you cannot disable SSH on your modem/router, you could try port forwarding another port (2222 for example) to port 22 on your Linux server.

Comment: You may be onto something, though it's confusing me greatly. I've been playing with other ports like 8022 as well, but eventually I settled on the default port for testing. As mentioned, the connection timed out if I enabled the firewall on the SSH server. However, I found now that removing the port forwarding completely still gave me the "refused key" so something must be still open. Perhaps the router has a default 22 mapping. I can access the router locally via SSH ok.

Comment: In addition, the `auth.log` on the server gave me failed connections from other countries when I tested port 22 open, suggesting some probers had detected my IP as accessible. But using PuTTY's log I have confirmed that the router's SSH version matches the `dropbear` mentioned in the log.

Comment: Ok, further testing has revealed that my SSH server _is_ accessible from a remote computer (tested from a VPN), but not my Windows 7 PuTTY client locally through the public IP. It looks like the router has some built-in port mapping for 22 to itself that only applies locally, perhaps based on source addresses. It sees the source is a local address and overrides the port forwarding rule. Bothersome. Changing the server's port to 2222 gives me connection refused on the Win7 box, works from the VPN.

Comment: port forward works only from WAN to LAN as your local computer comes from inside the network even if you put the public IP as destination address it does not leave the router as it knows it is its own IP so you dont hit the WAN interface as the traffic does not go to the internet and comes back on your WAN Public IP. so from inside the network you have to use the internal IP and port 22 (as your config  is set) and from external to the public IP and the port you set to be forwarded (which usually can't be 22 as routers are linux boxes with blocked access from WAN to port 22 by default)